# How I solve the error "sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface"

Tags: go

How I solve the error "sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface"

I want to create Delete function in golang.
I think that

```
ids_interface := []interface{}{}
    for id := range ids{
        ids_interface = append(ids_interface, id)
    }
```

this code is mistake.

```
func String(ids []int64) string {
    ans := strings.Builder{}
    for i := 0; i < len(ids); i++ {
        ans.WriteString(strconv.FormatInt(ids[i], 10))
        if i != len(ids)-1 {
            ans.WriteRune(',')
        }
    }
    return ans.String()
}
// DeleteTODO deletes TODOs on DB by ids.
func (s *TODOService) DeleteTODO(ctx context.Context, ids []int64) error {
    const deleteFmt = `DELETE FROM todos WHERE id IN (?%s)`
    str_ids := String(ids)
    deleteFmt_str := fmt.Sprintf(deleteFmt, str_ids)
    ids_interface := []interface{}{}
    for id := range ids{
        ids_interface = append(ids_interface, id)
    }
    stmt,err := s.db.PrepareContext(ctx,deleteFmt_str)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("server/todo.go update prepareContext ",err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()
    res, err := stmt.ExecContext(ctx,ids_interface)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    rows,err := res.RowsAffected()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("server/todo.go stmt.RowsAffected()",err)
    }
    if rows != 1 {
        errors := model.ErrNotFound{ErrorWhen:time.Now(),ErrorWhat: "it didn't work"}
        return &errors
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Since you're using fmt.Sprintf to inject the ids directly into the query string you do not need to use `ids_interface`, remove it completely. Also remove the `?` from `... IN(?%s)`. And since the resulting query will have no parameter placeholders and the prepared statement is not reused, there is no need for the db.Prepare either. Just use `db.ExecContext(query)`. However keep in mind that injecting the ids directly into the query string instead of using a prepared statement with placeholders is only secure because you're dealing with integers rather than text...

Comment: ... but even though it should be safe from sql injection attacks, it could still be considered bad practice.